# Eloquent relationships: accessing all grandchildren resources from a root model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application, I have `Users` which can have many `Accounts`. In those accounts there are grandchildren models like `Videos`. In my routing scheme, I would like an Index route which lists all Videos of all Accounts related to a User.

To do this, it doesn't seem like keeping a `user_id` on the `videos` table is necessary unless I am mistaken. I believe Eloquent should be able to traverse this relationship and get all Videos of all Accounts related to a User. Ultimately, this is using a FormRequest which, in my VideoController, looks like:

```php
public function index(VideoIndexRequest $request)
{
    return VideoResource::collection($request->user()->videos()->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(15));
}
```

On the User model, I've tried adding a relationship method like so:

```php
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->accounts()->with('videos');
}
```

... but what I am returned via the API is a single Video object with null values (no data). Instead, what works in my User model is the following (essentially saying, "get all videos whose account ID is in this array").

```php
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
}

public function videos()
{
    return Video::whereIn('account_id', $this->accounts()->pluck('id')->toArray());
}
```

... but this doesn't seem as elegant. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User** hasMany `accounts`, and **Account** hasMany `videos`. 
To achieve all *videos* from the **User** model,   you can define a **[hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)** relationship :

```
public function videos()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
       'App\Video', // Videos model
       'App\Account', // Account model
       'user_id', // Foreign key on accounts table...
       'account_id', // Foreign key on videos table...
       'id', // Local key on users table...
       'id' // Local key on accounts table...
   );
}
```